# C# remove part of string in Time

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have this being outputted

**09:19:30.5070000 AM**

but I wanted to look like this **09:19:30 AM**

how can I remove those extra milliseconds at the end of the string using code?

Is being stored in `time.Text`

Thanks in advance.

Comment: `DateTime` has various `ToX` methods, including a `ToString` overload that accepts a custom format string. `ToShortDate` sounds like the one you want.

Comment: [Standard Date and Time Format Strings](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/az4se3k1.aspx)

Comment: where are you getting the time from? DateTime? Some other way?

Comment: I just need to truncate those last 8 characters, pretend is not time. How do you truncate the last 8 characters?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
string time = "09:19:30.5070000 AM";

StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(time);
string final = sb.Remove(8, 8).ToString();
```

Comment: Thanks man, it worked great. You are the only one who understood my question. Don't know why I got voted down so many times.

Answer (score 4):

`DateTime.ToString("T")` should work I think.

Comment: Not always, if the OP expects the hours to have `0` at the beginning regardless of the number - this varies based on culture i.e. `09:19:30 AM` is `9:19:30 AM` in `en-US`.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this if its a `string` :

```
string strDate = "09:19:30.5070000 AM";
DateTime datDate;           
if (DateTime.TryParseExact(strDate,"hh:mm:ss.fffffff tt",
    System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture,
    System.Globalization.DateTimeStyles.None, out datDate))
{
    //Console.WriteLine(datDate.ToString("hh:mm:ss tt"));
     time.Text=datDate.ToString("hh:mm:ss tt");

}
```